# Magento Export for products broken

Tags: magento

I have a magento issue exporting products, on one magento install, it works perfectly, on an identical magento install on the same server... it does not.... here's a video showing the problem...

before getting to run the export, the page is blank where the attributes should be... I am showing it working in the first store, and not in the second in the video! any help is greatly appreciated.
obviously, watching the video in HD will show the text clearly.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLrKPKosHo0

Comment: Check file permissions, make sure all folders are CHMOD to 755 and files are 644 and the file/folder OWNER/GROUP are set correctly.  Also check your **var/logs** and **var/report** folders to see if there are any errors (be sure to enable logging in the Magento configuration first, then run the export and check).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply... I did the logging, and nothing from that... the import/export folders are permissions proper.... any other folders that would be related? - I had installed a module for featured products and it left behind an attribute when I uninstalled it... I have since removed that attribute through SQL...  and still the export is broken... (and I am having issues with a Advanced Import profile that used to work and doesn't now.)

Comment: Open the console in your browser developer tools (Firebug for Firefox is what I recommend) and look for the **POST** url.  Open that upon and see what the **RESPONSE** is.  There is most likely a PHP error being returned in there.  This may help you find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Done! that shows a 500 error.... not on the customer export, but on the product export!!!! its like this: XXXXXXXXX.com/index.php/customadmin/export/getFilter/key/ceaf151180ec4ad5ba4a17801fe31d9a/entity/catalog_product ? isAjax=true 500 Internal Server Error 1.51s

Comment: Ok, now check your server logs.  It will be the `apache_error.log` file, or the `php_error.log` file etc in your **server log** directory. (assuming that you're running apache)

Comment: done, and now I definitely see something wrong... local.xml is set to 551... errors are: (13)Permission denied: file permissions deny server access: /www/sites/domainhere/files/html/app/etc/local.xml and also: FastCGI: server "/www/sites/domainhere/files/cgi-bin/php5.external" stderr: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in /www/sites/domainhere/files/html/app/code/local/CommerceExtensions/Productimportexport/Model/Convert/Adapter/Productimport.php on line 1911

Comment: Ok, so now you know the issue is related to either of those.  Looks like a 3rd party extension is causing the issue.  Remove it and try to export.

Comment: Thank you so much, this led me into the direction to get this matter resolved... it ended up being orphan and duplicate category names by a faulty import, which broke everything else. - Appreciate your help!